# jQuery drag and drop over reflowable content

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am currently designing an inline text editor. Users will have the ability to drag and drop images into the editor anywhere they want.

The editor is entirely `iFrame` based, heavily relying on nested `div`s for styling and formatting. Now if I the user drags the image into the middle of the content and drops it there, I want that the content above the drop zone be packaged into one `div`, the image being placed below it, and the content below the drop zone packaged into another `div` and placed below the image.

But I have no idea how to split a `div` into two parts based on co-ordinates (which can be obtained from the jQuery drop handler). Can anyone give me an idea on how to do it?

Comment: not the best idea but you could put each word in an inline element (ex:span) and  get the span at the specified co-ordinates

Comment: Wow that looks insanely complicated! Basically I am designing a RTE, where the user can paste a chunk of content, copy and paste an image from their hard drive, etc. So say a chunk of text is pasted, it is difficult to tokenize each word into a span. How come then MS Word do it?

Comment: `How come then MS Word do it` They have more than just a few developers at Microsoft. I can assure you MS Word is indeed a very complex application.

Comment: Okay. But they surely do it with some logic, right? I just want to understand that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think i get the gist of what you are trying to do and i made a short script to demonstrate one possibilty. I split the text into one div per character, and make those divs sortable so i can drag and drop position my image in the middle of the text

HTML

```
<span class="sortable">
       <img id="image" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1842775519/profile_normal.png" />
        <input type="text" size="1" id="tb"/>
</span>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $(".sortable").sortable();  //Makes panel sortable (needs jquery and jquery UI)
    $("#tb").keyup(function () { //binds keyup event on the input box
        $('<div>' + $(this).val() + '</div>').insertBefore(this);  //adds the input box value to a new div and inserts it into the DOM before the input box itself
        $(this).val(''); // empties the input
    });
});
```

CSS

```
* {
    float:left
}
.sortable {
    border: solid 1px black;
    width:200px;
    float:left
}
```

see a working fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/urbanbjorkman/cFfS9/1/

This might be a bit of a mad hatter solution large chunks of text . And it still needs a lot of work (obviously since this is only a couple of lines of javascript)

But it would not be inconcievable to keep the text in one div. And then to split it into separate elements on the sortstart event. And on the sortstop event join all connecting texts back together and leaving the image where it is. thus giving you what you asked for with a div split in two with the image inbetween.

Comment: Can you explain the logic? How is it working for an `input` element also?

Comment: i added some comments to the javascript code. And the logic is basically this: I split the text into one div per character, and make those divs sortable so i can drag and drop position my image in the middle of the text

Comment: Where are you breaking the text into `div`s? You are just inserting a new text input every time a `keyup` is fired.

Comment: You asked for a script with inputs instead of divs? The original fiddle uses divs. If my little script is to complicated then i suggest that you go with a third party editor like Kendo http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/index.html

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I didn't notice. You declared the `span` as `sortable`, does that make all its children `sortable`? And secondly, how can a `div` be put inside a `span`?

Comment: Yes. Sortable makes its children sortable. I updated the fiddle to use div instead of span, it makes no difference whatsoever for my example.

Answer (score 0):

Your question confuses me a little. But have you looked into draggables and sortables from the jQuery UI api.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

They're good for enabling self sorting containers. And given that they apply to divs you should be able to get them to work for this. (given a bit of jQuery elbow-grease)

Comment: See, in a RTE, the user starts typing something, just like in Word or GMail compose widget. They also might paste a chunk of text/graphics/multimedia from some source and paste it in one go. So after he has a pasted a chunk of text, say 30 lines, he wants to insert an image i between the 10th and 11th line. So the first 10 lines now should wrap up in one `div`i, the lines 11-20 in another, and the image be placed in between...